# GCP Service Account List Billing Accounts NodeJs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-api

We are trying to retrieve the list of billing accounts in GCP, for that purpose, we are using a Service Account. The code that we wrote goes as follows:

```
async function listBillingAccounts(project)
{
    let keys = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(process.env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_BASE64_JSON, "base64").toString("ascii"));
    const client = new CloudBillingClient({credentials : keys});
    if (project !== undefined)
    {
        const [accounts] = await client.listBillingAccounts({ project, });
        console.log(accounts);
    }
    else
    {
        const [accounts] = await client.listBillingAccounts({});
        console.log(accounts);
    }
    console.info(`found ${accounts.length} billing accounts:`);
    for (const account of accounts) {
        console.info(`${account.displayName}:`);
        console.info(`\topen: ${account.open}`);
        console.info(`\tparentBillingAccount: ${account.masterBillingAccount}`);
    }
}
```

**SERVICE_ACCOUNT_BASE64_JSON** constains the Service Account information:

```
{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "xxxx",
    "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "xxxxx@xxxxx",
    "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxxxx"
}
```

No mater if we specify or not the project name, accounts result is always an empty array. Do you know what can be happening? We ask to IAM Team if the service account has the required permissions and they confirm that it has:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-billing.readonly --> Billing Account Usage Commitment Recommender Viewer is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

The results are empty because the service account is not authorized to view billing accounts.

You must add the service account email address to each billing account as an authorized user with the role Billing Account Viewer (roles/billing.viewer). ***The role is added to the billing account***.

[Overview of Cloud Billing access control](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access)